# Open Layers 3 - get vector type (line, polygon, point) from dropped in vector data

Tags: jquery, openlayers-3

OpenLayers 3 has a great drag and drop feature.  The example is given here:

http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/drag-and-drop.html

Within the event handler for the drag and drop you can access the vector layer that has been dragged in (vectorSource) in this case:

```
dragAndDropInteraction.on('addfeatures', function(event) {
    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
      features: event.features
    });
    map.addLayer(new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: vectorSource,
      style: styleFunction
    }));
    map.getView().fit(
        vectorSource.getExtent(), /** @type {ol.Size} */ (map.getSize()));
  });
```

vectorSource can be seen here being created from event.features, however I can't find a way of telling whether the vector that's been dropped into the map is of type **polygon**, **point** or **line**.

My question is, is there a way of telling what vector type the data is?

`console.log(event.features);` shows that there is a geometry term in there, but I'm not sure how that reliably gives me data type.

I need to know for my layer management tool so that I can correctly represent the vector layer.

I have tried:

```
event.features[0].getGeometry();
event.features[0].getGeometryName();
```

Neither seem to produce the information I need.

Comment: Although Danilo's answer covers the question, but when creating features, you can add some custom parameters to them. And then on actions you can get those params of the object. That can help if you have, for example, two types of points and you want to know which one is which.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I don't know what the data type is when it's loaded in, not necessarily that they get confused with others.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a feature, you can retrieve its Geometry and then its Type:

```
feature.getGeometry().getType()
```

> The geometry type. One of 'Point', 'LineString', 'LinearRing',
>   'Polygon', 'MultiPoint', 'MultiLineString', 'MultiPolygon',
>   'GeometryCollection', 'Circle'.

Reference: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.geom.html#GeometryType

Comment: I'm afraid with event.features[0].getGeometry() I just get an object returned which doesn't seem to contain useful information, and event.features[0].getGeometryName() just gives 'geometry' as a response.