# Get geometry type from OpenLayers feature

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to get the geometry type from a feature in OpenLayers, but I cannot find any solution. Before version 3.5.0 there was a method feature.getGeometry().getType()

https://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/apidoc/ol.geom.Geometry.html#getType

This solution was also recommended in stackoverflow:

[Open Layers 3 - get vector type (line, polygon, point) from dropped in vector data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36933301/open-layers-3-get-vector-type-line-polygon-point-from-dropped-in-vector-da)

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163699/retrieve-geometry-type-point-line-polygon-from-ol3-feature

The proposed method doesn't exist any more (I am using OL 4.6.5). Is there any other solution available?

Answer (score 2):

Well... it seems that feature.getGeometry().getType() still works. I have no idea, why it didn't work in some cases.